# File upload fields reset after JavaScript function is called

Tags: javascript, html, file, upload

I have a link which generates file upload fields through a JavaScript function. However, when I add an upload field, then select a file, then add another field, the file disappears from the first field. I don't see why this should be happeneing.

jsFiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/etCqD/

Note that the jsFiddle gives an error `'addPhoto() is not defined'` which I also don't understand as the function is clearly defined in the JavaScript section. This error doesn't happen on my actual page. Can someone tell me what's going on here?

Comment: "Note that the jsFiddle gives an error 'addPhoto() is not defined' which I also don't understand as the function is clearly defined in the JS section." — Look at your preferences on the left hand side. The code is being wrapped in a function assigned to `onload`. That means that `addPhoto` is scoped to that function and not accessible form outside it (e.g. from the intrinsic event attribute that [you should not be using anyway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript))

Comment: Indeed, I didn't realize that preference was there - must have been left over from some previous fiddle I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are editing the `innerHTML`. This means that you serialise the DOM to HTML then change the HTML and convert the HTML back to DOM.

This destroys the value since:

- The `value` attribute will contain the default value
- You can't set a `value` attribute for file inputs

Use [`createElement`, `appendNode` and friends](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Creating_and_modifying_HTML#Creating_HTML) instead.

Comment: Thanks, appendChild did the trick, looked like the easiest one to use. Will accept your answer in 5 minutes.